# What exactly does a multi-output function in Matlab return?

Tags: matlab, function, scilab, referential-transparency, multiple-variable-return

Disclaimer: I'm actually using Scilab, but it's mostly very similar to MATLAB, and based on my research it seems the same phenomenon happens with MATLAB.

In MATLAB, functions can be multi-output. Suppose we have a function `function [a, b] = f(x)`. If I type:

```
c = f(x)
```

Then `c` is given the value of the first output. If I type:

```
[a, b] = f(x)
```

Then `[a, b]` is given the value of the pair of both outputs. This seems to imply that MATLAB doesn't have [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29). What is the actual value of the expression `f(x)`? What's going on?

Comment: Yes, Matlab is not referential transparent. Otherwise, you could index the result of a function. I think it is to make programming 'easier' because some functions have "less important" stuff as 2nd and 3rd output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases the number of requested outputs changes the behaviour, particularly when a function is called with no output arguments.

For example, this simply plots a histogram of the data in `a` with the default settings:

```
hist(a);
```

The next returns the histogram data into `N`.  No plot is produced:

```
N = hist(a);
```

However, if we ask for two outputs (`X` is now the bin centres) we can plot the histogram with `bar` (which is what `hist` uses internally to plot if no output arguments are given):

```
[N, X] = hist(a);
bar(X,N);
```

This behaviour is controlled by checking `nargout`, and can be incorporated into your own functions.

Comment: This make sense! Just made a comment on this on the other solution.

Comment: In the first case we have `nargout=0`, the second `nargout=1` and the third `nargout=2`?

Comment: @JackM And `[N, ~] = hist(a);` would also have `nargout` as `2`.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the function `f(x)` normally returns 2 outputs. However, when called with only one output argument, it will return only the first one (`a` in your case). In MATLAB, you can also specify that you are not interested in a particular output by using `~`:

```
[~,b] = f(x);
[a,~] = f(x); % equivalent to a = f(x)
```

Comment: So basically in matlab you don't "call a function", you "call a function for a specific set of outputs"?

Comment: Well, it's semantics.. In MATLAB, you "call a function", which returns one or more outputs (or sometimes none, depending on the function). You can use `nargout` in the body of the function to determine how many output arguments are called and what to return. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-number-of-function-arguments.html.

Comment: Well, the first output is not always equivalent to the only output case. For example, when you use `idx = find()`, `idx` will give you the linear index. But, if you do - `[idx,~] = find()`, `idx` will be the row index. Most MATLAB built-in functions use `nargout` (which you have just mentioned about) to detect and accordingly output values. `nargout` will be `2` with both of these - `[a,b] = some_func1` and `[a,~] = some_func1` and that's what I think MATLAB uses to decide what to output.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for the comment, nkjt's answer illustrates it well.